# RISCV DCache.scala state machine and working flow

Tags: rocket-chip

Hi can anybody explain to me the riscv processor L1 data cache (DCache.scala) state machine and working flow. i am very new to scala and riscV. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this question is too broad to answer. You have to be familiar with two specific topics for this: Scala language syntax/semantics and RISC-V processor architecture. That is too much for one question :) Please search for specific stuff, and ask specific questions in case you can't find answers by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @vadipp for your replay yes DCache is very broad so the state machine. i did not found any document about it. Some guidance in it can be given. unfortunately i did not found stuff on it so asked here